# Linked list failing delete

Tags: c, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a linked list defined like this

```
typedef struct Elem Elem;

struct Elem {
    int val;
    Elem *next;
};
```

and i wrote two list delete function
the first:

```
void free_list(Elem** head) {
        if (!*head)
            return;
        if (!(*head)->next) {
            free(*head);
            *head = 0;
            return;
        }
        free_head(&((*head)->next));
    
}
```

and the second

```
void free_list(Elem** head) {
    while (*head) {
        Elem *tmp = *head;
        head = &((*head)->next);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the two function works on mac os without problems, while the second doesn't work on ubuntu, indeed when i execute it appear this error

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dump)
```

So i suppose that the second is wrong, but i don't see the error

Comment: `head = &((*head)->next);` - what does `head` now hold the address of ? Ans: the `next` pointer of a node. In fact, the very node you're about to destroy with `free(tmp);`. The statement `head = &((*head)->next);` is synonymous with `head = &tmp->next;`, and the node pointed to by `tmp` is about to go bye bye. The ensuing dereference with `while (*head)` invokes undefined behavior. Change that line to be `*head = tmp->next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both functions are incorrect.

The first function

```
void free_head(Elem** head) {
        if (!*head)
            return;
        if (!(*head)->next) {
            free(*head);
            *head = 0;
            return;
        }
        free_head(&((*head)->next));
    
}
```

deletes only the last node in the list because deleting a node occurs only in this if statement

```
        if (!(*head)->next) {
            free(*head);
            *head = 0;
            return;
        }
```

The second function is wrong because it does not set to NULL the pointer to the head node and moreover it assigns the pointer head with the address of the data member `( *head )->next` while the node containing this data member is being deleted. SO the function has undefined behavior.

```
void free_head(Elem** head) {
    while (*head) {
        Elem *tmp = *head;
        head = &((*head)->next);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
void free_head( Elem **head ) 
{
    while ( *head ) 
    {
        Elem *tmp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}
```

And the recursive function can look like

```
void free_head( Elem **head ) 
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        Elem *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
        free_head( head );
    }
}
```